# Вы не прошли проверку?

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок

Речь про эту проверку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/208391

По комментариям я сделал вывод, что автор разобрался с проблемой и вопрос можно закрыть, как "проблема, которая больше воспроизводится".

Может я неправильно использую эту причину закрытия?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не важно, разобрался автор или нет. Важно, что вопрос может быть полезен другим. Насколько я понимаю, проблема вполне должна воспроизводиться, если повторить сделанные действия. В любом случае, закрывать этот вопрос, да ещё и при налии подробного ответа, не стоит.

Вот типичный пример того, что больше не воспроизводится: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/737065/178988

Comment: Но я же в очереди не вижу, был ответ или нет. В данном случае не стал переходить по ссылке на вопрос, показалось, что по комментарием всё очевидно.

Comment: Разве? Вообще-то справа показывается, но вполне возможно, что проверка действительно отображает там нули.

Answer (score 2):

Эту причину закрытия стоит использовать только в тех случаях, которые прямо упоминаются в тексте причины:

- Есть вопрос с кодом / конфигом, код правильный, но не работает из-за того, что в каком-то месте автор вопроса *случайно нажал не ту кнопку* на клавиатуре. Т.е. именно опечатался. А не просто проявил незнание языка / платформы / еще чего-то.
- Есть вопрос без точных шагов для воспроизведения проблемы, и автор в комментариях написал "хм, странно, ничего не делал - само прошло!"